# RQDA batch file import not working

Tags: r, rstudio, rqda

I am trying to import multiple files into RQDA like this:

```
#install.packages("RQDA")
library(RQDA)
#import list of files into program
files<-list.files("C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\SNA_R_Class_code\\Texts")
RQDA()
setwd("C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\SNA_R_Class_code")
openProject("me_classify_class_texts.rqda") #this is a completely empty project I just created
write.FileList(files)
```

When I look at the RDQA GUI it shows no project open, I get the following message in RStudio console: `NA exists in the database!`

When I manually start RQDA and open a project the run the final line of the code above I get the same result.

I can import files through the RQDA GUI fine however. What am I doing wrong with the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set a different file title for every file before it would import correctly